# Use window.print() after setTimeout() function with url redirection

Tags: javascript, window, settimeout, window.open

The big picture of requirement:

I am on PageA and on a Print button click, I wanted to get a print dialogbox on PageB after URL redirection in newTab from pageA.

Now, Url redirection in newtab for PageB takes a few seconds to hit the third-party API and preview a document after receiving the response.

Now the requirement is, I am on PageA and getting redirected to PageB by Javascript function window.open("url_for_PageB","_blank")(*newTab is mandatory*). Now I want to open print dialogBox which gets appear by window.print on pageB.

I tried below code to print the content on PageB:

1. This is working for PageB and I am able to open print dialogbox on PageB, but I have not received the complete response from API. So, in preview of Print dialog box, the real resposne is missing.

   window.open('url',_blank).print();

Note: if some how, we can mange to use setTimeout() before printing, then we will get the complete response in interval and the complete data in preview.

2. Tried also with setTimeout function:

   window.open('url',_blank).setTimeout(window.print(),3000);

Note: This code is also not working.

Can anyone please help me with the above functionality.
If we get some timeInterval in between opening and printing the page then we will be able to capture the complete response in Preview of Print DialogBox.

Comment: There is no way to control an action of new page

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
let newWindow = window.open('url','_blank')
setTimeout(() => { newWindow.print() }, 3000);
```

The `window.open` method returns a object pointing to the new Window, as stated [in here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

> **Return value**
> A WindowProxy object, which is basically a thin wrapper for the Window object representing the newly created window, and has all its features available. If the window couldn't be opened, the returned value is instead null. The returned reference can be used to access properties and methods of the new window as long as it complies with Same-origin policy security requirements.

Then you call the `print` method of that object with a delay vía `setTimeout` function.

Comment: Thanks fo the answer, but, by using above code -  the setTimeout() is not working. Hence, I didn't get the complete response back before print preview.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? I've tested and works fine. But you need to define a proper delay for your needs (maybe 3 seconds y is too little and you need to make it wait longer)